# regex match files affected by the trojan cryptolocker

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match files with 6 random characters starting by a dot (.)

```
File examples:
document.xls.qwerty
document.pptx.asdass
File.doc.aaBBcc
```

The below regex match 6 chars at the end but also match long extension names files like file.xls.aabbccDDff

`[a-zA-Z]{6,6}$`

Comment: So, why not start with a dot? `\.[a-zA-Z]{6}$`?

Comment: Wiktor is spot on. You are not specifying the starting character, so as long as there are 6 random `[A-Za-z]` characters at the end, then it doesn't matter what preceded it (even if that was also a character in `[a-zA-Z]`). If you don't want to match the `.`, but you want to make sure it is a 6-character file extension, then you could also say: `(?<=\.)[a-zA-Z]{6}` (presuming the language supports lookbehind.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to match a dot, add `\.` in front:

```
\.[a-zA-Z]{6}$
```

Note `{6,6}` = `{6}`.

If you need to *extract* the letters, either capture them with `\.([a-zA-Z]{6})$` and access group 1 value, or use a lookaround, `(?<=\.)[a-zA-Z]{6}$`.